# iOS 7.0.3 Use user wallpaper as background

Tags: background, ios7, wallpaper

I use these following code run on iPhone 4S(iOS 7.0.2), it works fine. But on iPhone 5s(iOS 7.0.3), it doesn't work! And the passbook app still has the same. How can I fix my problem?

```
[[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] _setApplicationIsOpaque:NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

[self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MainBackground.png"]]];

and put below line in every screen's viewDidLoad method

[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];